# How to Load And Get Data from Database Inside foreach And Use if else there in php

Tags: php

How to get data from the database and display it inside the foreach that resides in the controller.

I have tried to do it, when I use code like below:

```
 public function submit(){
    $name = $this->request->post('text');

    $nameTags = getNameTag($name);

    if($nameTags) {
        foreach ($nameTags as $nameTag) {
            // Data from my model
            $data = $this->load->model('Tags')->getNameTag($nameTag);
            $found = $data->count;
            echo $found;
        }
    }

}
```

After I try to get data outside of foreach, the data appears, but when I try to insert into foreach, the result is 0, whereas in my database there is a text that should display value 1.

What should I do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$data = $this->load->model('Tags')->getNameTag($nameTag);` need to be `$data = getNameTag($nameTag);`.Also can you show the output of `print_r( $nameTags);`

Comment: Like this: in outside of foreach: `$data = $this->load->model('Tags');` after that in inside of foreach, I using something like this: `$datas = $data->getNameTag($nameTag);` I mean, like that? because I'm try but not work.

Comment: show use the output of `print_r( $nameTags);` first. put it after `$nameTags = getNameTag($name);` and check the output and show us

Comment: barcelona

`stdClass Object
(
    [count] => 0
)`

0
nothing

`stdClass Object
(
    [count] => 0
)`

Comment: `$nameTags = getNameTag($nama);` this is from textarea what I submit and I want to check it in database.

Comment: I think your function cose have some fault then. because it's showing 0 only

Comment: I don't know why it's not work, because I try to put in the above of foreach, it's still work. So I am confused, can not use the data called from the database inside the foreach?